Finding Fourier transform of $x$ by using the Fourier transform of $1$
We know:
$$\mathscr{F} 
\left\{1\right\} = \delta(\omega)$$
and also:
$$\mathscr{F}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(x)\, \mathrm dx\right\}=\frac{1}{i\omega}F(\omega)+\pi F(0)\delta(\omega),
$$
where $F(x)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.
Now my question is, is it possible to find the Fourier transform of $x$ using this information? I am struggling on how to get rid of $F(0) = \delta(0)$ since it is equal to $\infty$.
And assuming that is solved, is the Fourier transform undefined at $\omega = 0$ since we have division by $\omega$?

Can't you just take the integral expression for $\delta(\omega)$ and take a derivative of both sides with respect to $\omega$?

I don't understand how your second formula is useful since $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}f(x), \mathrm dx=\infty$ for $f(x)=1$ (and $t>-\infty$), but I believe the Differentiation property is useful.

How did you get $F(0)=\delta(0)$?

The Fourier transform of $f(x)=x$ can be found as follows.  Note that for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi\rangle &=\langle f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) \frac{d}{dk}e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{IBP}i\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\\\\
&=i2\pi \phi'(0)
\end{align}$$
Hence, in disrtibution we see that $\mathscr{F}\{f\}(x)=-i2\pi \delta'(x)$.
The Fourier transform $\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}+i\pi F(0)\delta(\omega)$ is a tempered distribution, not an ordinary function.  A tempered distribution  is a linear functional that maps Schwarz functions into numbers.  A tempered distribution does not take on values.  Hence it is meaningless to assign a value to $\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}+i\pi F(0)\delta(\omega)$ at $\omega =0$.
Note that both $\frac1\omega$ and $\delta(\omega)$ are tempered distributions.  The latter is the Dirac Delta while the former is defined in THIS ANSWER.

+1. You can also perhaps put a link to the principal value distribution in your last paragraph to help our OP ;)

@LL3.14 Thank you for the up vote and your suggestion.  I've edited accordingly.

Mark Viola's answer cannot be beaten with my answer :) Treat it as an addional note. There exists a general expression for Fourier Transform of $x^{n} f(x)$ which may be useful to you in future. As always, there are conditions that need to be satisfied before you can apply it, which you can refer to in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms (the note for $106$ is exactly what Mark Viola derived from first principles, I believe).

Edit: Adding mathjax, in case anyone finds my image objectionable.
$$\mathcal{F}[x^n f(x)](\xi) = \left(\frac{i}{2\pi n}\right)^{n} \frac{d^n \hat{f}(\xi)}{d \xi^n}$$
when Fourier Transform is defined as $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i2\pi \xi x} dx$$
